# Continuously monitoring a SQL Server a single table row for change with 'near-realtime' resolution

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, synchronization

I have an application that we access remotely which bring various clients into 'Context' to review their associated data as we move through the client list for the day. We move between these clients every few minutes (average 5 minutes, range 0-45 minutes as we may get interruptions).

I have a local application with access to the same Database that this remote application accesses.

I would like to 'slave' this application to the context in the other application running remotely. I cannot access the remote server application (to screen scrape or AutoIt it etc) but I can read a record from the Audit table of the last accessed patient by the same user.

Other than calling:

```
select CurrentPatientID 
from UserPreferenceTable 
where UserID = XXXXXXX
```

every 60 seconds, and then changing context in the local application, is there someway I can hold a ?pointer ?reference to that row, and just refresh the data which would be more efficient:

- reduce server load from getting to that data
- and allow to maybe improve resolution to 5 or 10 seconds

Comment: Seems like a job for [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Change tracking would help to know which records got modified..but if the master application only "moves" from one patient to another - this will **not** be detected by Change tracking feature, is it not ? @zohar-peled

Comment: @dmc2005, since each patient record is viewed for avg 5 minutes and sometimes upto 45mins, the master application can send an `event` or `message` to something like Azure Service Bus or any `AMQP` system, then your slave app can `subscribe` to those events and accordingly change context to that record.

Comment: You can check out SQLDependency if you're using C#, it's not perfect but not too bad either

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran It's been a long time since I've last done something like this, perhaps it was CDC? I'm not so sure now.

Comment: Create a SQL trigger that write the updates to another table and poll that table instead?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Unfortunately while I have read access to the database, it’s is a closed proprietary database that we can’t add triggers to.